# insertar resultado de operación lógica en mi tabla y mi BBDD

Tags: html

soy nuevo en este mundo.
Explico un poco mi código, estoy haciendo como parte de mi proyecto una página de préstamo sencilla, coloque en la línea 20-28 una operación lógica para obtener resultado de una simulación de préstamo,. Me informa de forma correcta el resultado. Pero.... necesito que ese resultado se muestre primero en el front de la tabla línea 138 en adelante, con el botón calcular y luego con el botón enviar se guarden los datos en la BBDD de los resultados.

espero me puedan ayudar. Un abrazo

```
<?php


require("Dconexion.php"); 
  $ObjConexion= new conexion(); {

  if($_POST){
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido=$_POST['apellido'];
    $cedula=$_POST['cedula'];
    $telMov=$_POST['telMov'];
    $telHab=$_POST['telHab'];
    $telOfi=$_POST['telOfi'];
    $importe=$_POST['importe'];
    $meses=$_POST['meses'];
    $tasa=$_POST['tasa'];
    $fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
    $gestion=$_POST['gestion'];

    $interesMes = $importe * ($tasa / 100);
    $interesDia = $interesMes / 30;
    $totalP = $importe + $interesMes;
    $prestamo =  $interesMes *  $meses  + $importe;
    
    
    print 'Meses Para Pagar : ' . $meses;
    print '<br> Interes Mensual a Pagar $/.    : ' . $interesMes;
    print '<br> Monto Total a Pagar $/. : ' . $prestamo; 

    

  /*  $sql="INSERT INTO `clientes` (`nombre`, `apellido`, `cedula`, `telfMov`, `telfHab`, `telfOfi`, `importe`, `meses`, `tasa`, `fecha`, `gestion`) VALUES ('".$nombre."', '".$apellido."', '".$cedula."', '".$telMov."', '".$telHab."', '".$telOfi."', '".$importe."', '".$meses."', '".$tasa."', '".$fecha."', '".$gestion."');";
    $ObjConexion->execute($sql); 
    echo '<script> alert("REGISTRO DE CLIENTE EXITOSO");</script>'; 
    exit();  */

  }

  }
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>clientes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Dclientes.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="author" content="EnigmaticNerd"/>
        <meta name="description" content="transformar textos en css - cortar palabras largas con word-wrap - aprenderaprogramar.com"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="CSS, cursos, diseño, text-transform, word-spacing, cortar, aprenderaprogramar.com"/>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>

  </head>

    <body>

      <header>
        <div class="ancho">
          <div class="logo">
            <!-- <img src="logo.jpeg" alt="logo de patty cash"> -->
            <p><a href="Dclientes.php">PattyCash</a></p>
            </div>
              <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Servicio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>    
          </div>
      </header>

        <form name="" method="POST" action="Dclientes.php">
            <div>
            <div class="contenido1">
              <h1>Tipo</h1>
              <div>
                
                <input type="radio" value="simular" name="gestion">
                <label for="simular">Simular</label>
                <div class="check" required>
                <input type="radio" value="alta" name="gestion">
                <label for="alta">Alta</label>
                <div class="check" required>
                <input type="radio" value="pago" name="gestion">
                <label for="pago">Pago</label>
                <div class="check" required>
                </div>


                    <span><b><i>Nombre</i></b></span>
                    <input type="Nombre" name="nombre" id="" placeholder="Dame un Nombre">

                    <span><b><i>Apellido</i></b></span>
                    <input type="text" name="apellido" id="" placeholder="Dame un Apellido">

                    <span><b><i>Cédula</i></b></span>
                    <input  type="text" name="cedula" id="" placeholder="Dame una Cédula" min="0" max="8">

                    <span><b><i>Teléfono Celular</i></b></span>
                    <input type="telMov" name="telMov" id="" placeholder="041X-000-0000" min="0" max="11">

                    <span><b><i>Teléfono Habitación</i></b></span>
                    <input  type="telHab" name="telHab" id="" placeholder="0212-000-0000" min="0" max="11"> 

                    <span><b><i>Teléfono Oficina</i></b></span>
                    <input type="telOfi" name="telOfi" id="" placeholder="0212-000-0000" min="0" max="11">
          </div>
            <div class="contenido2">
              <h2>Simulador</h2>
                <span class="label"><b><i>Importe del Préstamo</i></b></span>
                <input class="importe" type="number" name="importe" min="50" max="5000" id="" placeholder="Necesito $">
                <span class="label"><b><i>meses</i></b></span>
                <input class="meses" type="number" name="meses" min="1" max="12" id="" placeholder="Meses">

                <span class="label"><b><i>Tasa de Interes</i></b></span>
                <input class="tasa" type="number" min="10" max="20" name="tasa" id="" placeholder="% Interes">
                
                <span class="date"><b><i>Fecha</i></b></span>
                <input type="fecha" id="" name="fecha" value="22-07-2018"> 
       
                <span class="label"><b><i>Frecuencia de Pago</i></b></span>
                <select name="frecuencia" id="" class="cuotas">
                <option value= "Frecuencia">Frecuencia</option>
                <option value="Semanal">Semanal</option>
                <option value="Quincenal">Quincenal</option>
                <option value="Mensual">Mensual</option>
                </select>
          </div>           
            <div class="acciones">
              <input class="limpiar" type="delete" id="btn_clean" value="Limpiar">
              <input class="calcular" type="calcular" id="calcular" value="Calcular">  
          </div> 

         
          <div class="container">

          <div class="contenido3">
            <h3>Cuadro de amortización</h3>
             <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Capital Vivo</th>
                    <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
                    <th scope="col">Interes</th>
                    <th scope="col">Amortización Interes</th>
                    <th scope="col">Amortización Capital</th>
                    <th scope="col">Saldo</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr class="table-primary">
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="table-warning">
                    <td scope="row">Item</td>
                    <td>Item</td>
                    <td>Item</td>
                    <td>Item</td>
                    <td>Item</td>
                    <td>Item</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
             </div>
            

          </div>
         
             


                    
                   


                    <input  class="aprobar" type="submit" value="Aprobar">
                </div>
                   
          </form>      


      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Tu pregunta sólo tiene a lo sumo 8 líneas y tu hablas de linea 20-28 y 138 en adelante. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Trata de crear un [mcve] o al menos copia y pega el código con el que estás trabajando. De lo contrario tu pregunta terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Buenos días, listo incluí mi código. Necesito sabes cómo puedo guardar el resultado de mi(s) calculo(s), ejemplo  "$interesMes = $importe * ($tasa / 100)" en la BBDD. colocando un $_POST o $_GET y me dice variable indefinida. En conclusión no sé cómo guardar  mis resultados en la BBDD sin que intervenga un Input. Estoy iniciándome con HTML, CSS y PHP. Gracias

Comment: Buenos días, será que aún no está clara mi solicitud. No he recibido ninguna respuesta.